# Align text inside children of Row widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-row, flutter-column

I am trying to generate the `legends` of the chart using the `Column` and `Row` widget dynamically. The issue that I am facing is aligning the text in the next row.

You can see that because of the larger text `Average` and `Sub-Pair` the next item in the column is moving towards the right. Not sure how to align all in a specific row and colmn.
[image]

Here is the code

```
  Widget _buildLegends() {
    return Column(
      children: List.generate(
        sectionDataList.length,
        (index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  indicatorDataList[index].subText,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 25,
                  width: 50,
                  color: indicatorDataList[index].color,
                ),
                Text(indicatorDataList[index].text),
                Text(
                  indicatorDataList[index].value.toString(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly give width of all four column using `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you are trying to say here

Comment: From the above pic that you showed it has 4 Columns right? (Good, greenColor ,65%,72) . Dont Use Expanded or Default width.

Explicitly give width of all four column using MediaQuery.of(context).size.width